Identify older than 1995 sci-fi movie with an alien referred to as Xenomorph
I watched this as a teen, so it is probably dated before 1995.
If I remember correctly, one of the initial scenes was set on a space-ship and there were some heavy vault-like doors. I believe some kind of accident causes at least one of the sealed doors to open and an alien breaks free. Somehow, the alien (if my memory serves me right it was just referred to as a "Xenomorph" later) gets to Earth and thats where most part of the movie happened. Most likely it was "present" Earth, no future setting.

I can't see why this isn't a totally valid "identify this movie" question, so please leave a comment if you down-vote and explain what should be improved.

+1 Yeah, people on this site are weird.

I also asked this question over at scifi.stackexchange and someone pointed me to a US miniseries from 1988 called "Something is Out There", what turned out to be correct. It can be found on Youtube. This is the scene on the spaceship that i (more or less) described.
